# ¿Como coloco en un Material Search View el icono para abrir el Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un ( Material Search View ) y un ( Navigation Drawer ), y no se como colocar el icono para abrir el Navigation...

este es el codigo normal para cuando es un `Toolbar`, pero con Material Search View no se como es..

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, 
                      R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te refieres al icon de la hamburguer al lado izquierdo del SearchView ?

Comment: si, para que me aparezca al dar clic el navigation

Comment: Agrega tu layout por favor.